# Facebook Like Box blank, asking to login, when user isn't logged into facebook

Tags: html, facebook-likebox

Created a like box from here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

got this code:

```
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/NLP-Coaching-Institute-of-California/187804434598142" 
data-width="197" data-height="338" data-show-faces="true" data-stream="false" 
data-header="true"></div>
```

but when users are not logged in, we get a blank box that says "Facebook Public Profile. Please log in to see content".

[image: Image here:]

Age restrictions are set to 13+, that should have taken care of it but didn't.

site domain: nlpca(dot)com

How do we always show the like box with content?

Answer (score 0):

You have to have the Facebook SDK included at least once in your page, preferably right after the opening body tag. Add this code to your page then give it a shot.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Comment: That code is already added. The like box works when people are logged in. It gives the above message, "Log in to see content" when people are not logged in.